# How to properly create a response after resolving controller arguments, but before controller is called?

Tags: symfony

I was wondering what's the proper way to stop execution of a controller after arguments are resolved.

For [ControllerArgumentsEvent](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.1/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/Event/ControllerArgumentsEvent.php) it's not possible to set a response, instead you can change the controller.
I was wondering if that's the "proper" way, since it essentially redirects the request to a different place.

I cannot do my logic before arguments are resolved, since I use something that is injected into the controller to determine appropriate action.

It seems the Sensio/FrameworkExtraBundle just throws exceptions in these cases, which I suppose I could do.

Comment: i dont quite see why you would want that instead of early returning a RedirectResponse from your controller

Comment: You can use setArgument in the event to set a custom argument based on your logic and then a switch case in the Controller to determine the correct Response although like the previous comment, I don't see why you can't just do it the normal way instead of using event.

Comment: Changing the controller to one that simply redirects is indeed, somewhat sadly, the proper way.  As some of the other posters have indicated, I'm not sure you actually need this but if you do then you do.  It would have been nice if the event had allowed setting a response like some of the other listener events do but it does not.  I even remember checking the Kernel::handle method where all the magic takes place but no workaround was found.

Comment: @johnSmith annotation-based control over an endpoint

Comment: @Akhil yet this does forces an implementation in each method, instead of simply the event subscriber